# Exception: Unable to generate build files for window build

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, flutter-desktop

while trying to run flutter desktop application I am getting this issue,I  installed visual studio 2019 (v 16.10.1 latest) and all the set up has been done as mentioned in documentation. Here is the snippet from flutter doctor.
[Flutter Doctor snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2OXJ.png)

The issue is that while running default counter app in window desktop I am getting error saying

> Exception: Unable to generate build files
> [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivibE.png)

There is no detail error or log for this, please can anyone tell me what is the issue here.
**Updated:**
So I trun command `flutter -v run -d windows`   and I got this error
[In log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7EXu.png). Please let me know what is this issue about
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, I spend three days on this,I thought it was laptop issue.
It is weird because in error it does't say anything.

All I had to do was download and install [visual studio redistributable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0).

Comment: that didnt work for me