# Flutter: Unable to generate build files for desktop

Tags: flutter, dart, ubuntu

Just today I was running my app on linux but now I can't run it as it gives me this error whenever I try running the app. I don't know what's wrong with it

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: undefined symbol: g_tls_channel_binding_error_quark
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
/snap/flutter/130/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gdk-pixbuf-2.0/../../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so
Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
CMake Error at /snap/flutter/130/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:463 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /snap/flutter/130/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:643 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/desktop_webview_auth/linux/CMakeLists.txt:21 (pkg_check_modules)


Exception: Unable to generate build files
Exited (sigterm)
```

```
flutter doctor

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.8, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-52-generic, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.3)
[✓] VS Code
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install clang cmake ninja-build pkg-config libgtk-3-dev`

and this two

`flutter config --enable-linux-desktop`

`sudo apt install liblzma-dev`

Comment: I have tried them all

Comment: what are the outputs of that? means any error occurs?
and which ide you using?

Comment: All the commands went through successfully but still facing the same problem. I am using vscode

Comment: Okay @Samuel Please check this link might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/67937531/11893675